# Displays twice the same data in recycle view when ever intent back to my activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created an activity where chat messages are been displayed using firebase. At the first time when we open our activity, it works fine and shows the message from the database once and looks good but as soon as we send a new message or try to intent to a new activity and as soon as we come back to the same activity where a message is been displayed. On that activity, the chat data are been displayed three times and again we send the message it displays the message four-time... as I am new to android field I have tried all my ideas but none of them works.

below are the codes of the onstart method of the personalchat activity which contain recycler view and when it started I connect to the message adopter which then performs the process of passing the value to the recycle view using the message class which retrieves the data from the database.

personalchat.java

```
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    rootRef.child("Message").child(CurrentUserId).child(msgReciverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
          message cMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(message.class);
          messageList.add(cMessage);
          messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          usermsglist.smoothScrollToPosition(usermsglist.getAdapter().getItemCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Message_adapter.java

```
 public class message_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<message_adapter.MessageViewHolder> {
private List<message> usermsgList;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference userref;
public message_adapter(List<message> usermsgList){
    this.usermsgList = usermsgList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.coustommsglayout,parent,false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    return new MessageViewHolder(view);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String msgsenderid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final message Message = usermsgList.get(position);
    String fromuserid = Message.getFfrom();
    String touserid = Message.getTo();
    final String fromMessageType = Message.getType();

    userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(fromuserid);
    userref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")){
              String reciverimage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
              Picasso.get().load(reciverimage).into(holder.reciverProfileImage);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    holder.recivermsgtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.reciverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.sendermsgtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.sendermsgImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.recivermsgImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.senderTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.reciverTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.senderimageTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.reciverimageTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (fromMessageType.equals("Text")){
       String Messagetime = Message.getTime();
       String Messagetext = Message.getMessage();
      textmsgmethod(msgsenderid,fromuserid,holder,Messagetime,Messagetext);
 }
```

Help me so that i can remove this error from my app project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onStart()` method is called every time you navigate back to your activity. So it's natural that you are getting duplicates every time you execute your Firebase child event listener:

```
rootRef.child("Message").child(CurrentUserId).child(msgReciverId).addChildEventListener(...)
```

You should move this call to your `onCreate()` method to avoid this.

Alternatively, you can just clear your recycler view items in your `onStop()` method.

Here's more information about the activity lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Also, you should use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` instead of `addValueEventListener(...)` in your `onBindViewHolder(...)` since `addValueEventListener(...)` will keep listening to your database changes whereas `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` only retrieves your data once.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to add the `addChildEventListener` in the `onStart` method so that every time the activity goes back-and-forth, you will be able to fetch the latest data from the Firebase.

You are getting duplicate data in the list because you are not clearing the `messageList` before adding data.

Try adding the line `messageList.clear` before `messageList.add(cMessage);` on your `onChildAdded` callback. This should work for you as expected.

Comment: I have tried this method, but when I send a new message it displays only the new message.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is from the onStart()
you have to use all those codes from your onCreate() or you can also move the code by creating a new method & you can call it from onCreate()

Comment: While this may answer the question, the answer is very unclear. It's important to explain what the problem is, not just where it is. Please also elaborate on what you mean by "codes".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).